# questions on implementing Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: “implements Runnable” vs. “extends Thread”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

I have two questions about multithreaded programming. I read a few answers on the internet, but still I can't find a satisfying answer.

1. Implementing the Runnable is preferred over extending the thread class.  Why?
2. How is it that we are able to get away with overriding just the run() method?

According to 'The Complete Reference to Java' by Herbert Schildt, If we are not overriding any methods of Thread class other than run(), it's better we implement Runnable.

My 2nd question might sound a bit silly, but I seem to be missing something and I'm not sure about how the whole thing works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1: Implementing the Runnable is preferred over extending the thread class. why?

Because it allows your class to extend another class if it wants to *instead* of being forced to extend `Thread`.

> 2: How is it that we are able to get away with over-ridding just the run() method?

You can certainly override other methods but the `Thread` object will call the `run()` method when the thread is started.  That's how it works.  The default `Thread.run()` method is:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

If you call the `Thread` constructor with a `Runnable` then that is what the `target` is set to.  If you instead extend `Thread` and `@Override` the `run()` method then that is the method that will be called when the thread object is started.

That's how the `Thread` class works.

> 2: How is it that we are able to get away with over-ridding just the run() method?

You may have misspoke here and were instead asking why we only need to *implement* the `run()` method in `Runnable()`.

- [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) is an interface with a single `run()` method that you *must* implement.
- [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) is a concrete class that you are *extending*.  You can override any methods in a concrete class unless the class is `final` or the method is `final`.

Make sure you use proper Java terminology and don't mixup `implement` and `override`.

Comment: @Gary-But we can implement a class only when we override all the methods of the class? as in a abstract class. Am i not right?

Comment: @vishnu You can't implement a class. You only extend it. See my answer.

Comment: @vishnu: If you are implementing an interface, you need to override all the methods in that interface unless your class is abstract. If you are extending an abstract class, you need to implement all abstract methods unless your class is itself abstract. If you are extending a non-abstract class, there is nothing to implement.

Comment: @vishnu  Jeremy and adarshr are spot on.  One more thing though.  `Thread` is actually a concrete class -- not abstract.  You can also extend concrete classes (that aren't final) and override concrete methods (again that aren't final).  `Thread.run()` is a concrete method in a concrete class.

Comment: @adarshr-ah mistake on my part. Pretty stupid i say. To make myself more clear i think i should rather put my question as..when i implement an interface i should override all the methods of the interface. But i'm overriding just run()

Comment: @JeremyHeiler-thanks that clears my doubt to some extent.

Comment: @vishnu `Thread` is a concrete class that you are _extending_.  `Runnable` is an interface with a single `run()` method that you need to implement.

Comment: @Gary-so implementing a concrete class is a bit different from implementing a interface. I hope i got it right

Comment: Additionally, there are a variety of utilities that accept `Runnable`s and do their own thread management on their own -- `ExecutorService`, for example.  Using `Runnable` lets you use those utilities or not as you desire.

Comment: @gary-please ignore my earlier comment. 
I get it now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @vishnu Make sure you use proper terminology.  You _extend_ an `abstract` or a concrete class.  You _implement_ an `interface`.  These terms are very important in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Three fundamentals before you delve deeper.

- A class can only `extend` one class.
- A class can `implement` any number of interfaces.
- An interface can `extend` any number of interfaces.

Additionally, an `abstract` class is a class. So it behaves like a class and you can't `implement` it. You only `extend` it.

Comment: my bad. Implement an interface.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of traps which can occur if you extend Thread which you don't get with implementing Runnable.

```
public static String getName() {
    return "My Test Application";
}

public static void stop() {
    System.out.println("Shutting down");
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(getName());
            stop();
        }
    }.run();
    System.out.println("Bye now.");
}
```

prints

```
Thread-0
Bye now.
```

See how many bugs you can spot.

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessary inheritance is generally a bad idea. You might hear "prefer composition over inheritance" often enough. I'm sure google can pull up enough links for you. The general issue is that inheritance bring tight, unnecessary coupling between classes.

Same goes for GUI components, btw.